# Moving Image Horizontally in steps

Tags: java, android, xml

Creating my first android app. I am close to being finished but need some help.

So, I have an image (its a pig) and I would like to move it horizontally in steps (not sliding). In better terms, I would like to delete the old image of the pig and move it horizontally to the right.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you'd let me know if my answer is correct for your question or not...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this, depending on what you actually want. I think that you should delete the old image and create a new one to the right. You should probably just change the LayoutParameters like this:

As long as you have your ImageView (or whatever it is) initialized in your `onCreate()` method, you can set a new location for it with this code:

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams param = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(int width, int height, int x, int y)
myImageView.setLayoutParams(param);
```

Where `x` is the new x value that you want, `y` is the new y value that you want, and the `width` and `height` are the width and height of your `ImageView`. You can get the current width and height with `myImageView.getWidth()` and `myImageView.getHeight()`. For the current x value, use `myImageView.getLeft()`, and for the current y value, use `myImageView.getTop()`.

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I am trying to use this however my program crashes. I have initialized the imageview in the onCreate() so im not to sure whats going on. Eclipse suggests that I put in a suppression warning for your code

Comment: I figured out a different way by using a button as a spacer and then decrementing the size of the button. Thanks for your help

Comment: @CraigNordquist interesting. Any chance you can tell me what the error message was that you were getting? I'm not sure what it could have been...